# After purging AirVPN wifi is still not working - how can I remove all traces of the changes made to my system by this software?

Tags: command-line, files, delete

How does a person remove/purge residual files after uninstalling/purging an application?

After uninstalling AirVPN Eddie client via

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge airvpn
```

I still have the affected (corrupted?) conf files in the `/etc` directory. I'm looking for other files that remain that are keeping my wifi from working. See this question:

[DNS conflicts & no connect wifi VPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982906/dns-conflicts-no-connect-wifi-vpn)

Right-clicking and deleting these files doesn't work. What is the proper command to take ownership of hidden and system files and delete them?

Comment: You should be able to delete any file with `sudo rm filename`, and any directory with `sudo rm -r dirname`, if you have sudo rights. Just be careful, and don't delete too much.

Comment: seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you [edit] your question to give the full story? We have told you how to purge packages but it didn't solve your problem, so tell us about the real problem...

Answer (score 1):

During the removal of package, corresponding `.prerm` and `.postrm` scripts (stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`) for the package *should* clean up and remove the files for the package, but those scripts may be missing removal for a few files or something failed in the process while script was running.

When a package is installed via `apt-get` or `apt`, there will be a `.list` file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` folder with list of all directories and files that were used by the package.  You could go over contents of that file and remove items individually via `sudo rm <filename>` command. One possible quick way to figure out which items from the list are still there would be to do the following:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; 
do 
    [ -f "$line" ] && printf "%s\n" "$line"  
done < /var/lib/dpkg/info/<PACKAGE-NAME>.list
```

Of course you could replace `printf` part with `rm`, and run this loop as root, but I wouldn't recommend doing that. Use discretion, verify each file is not used by something else and is actually something you can remove without breaking your system.

Comment: Thanks for this guide. Since it is a third party and trusted software >AirVPN Eddie client, this approach may not work. The "conf" files from network manager and resolv.conf need to be removed or editied for a fresh install of the client, to fix a DNS problem.